# Font isn't displayed correctly

Tags: html, css

This is the font I need to include: https://www.whatfontis.com/FF_Lobster-Two-Bold-Italic.font

This is the CSS I tried:

```
@font-face
{
    font-family: 'LobsterTwo';
    src: url("/fonts/LobsterTwo-BoldItalic.ttf")  format('truetype'),
}

#id{
    font-family: 'LobsterTwo';
}
```

It does have an effect, but only in making the text larger.

Some other issues:

1. I need eight four-by-four photo links with no space between them to occupy the whole width, I gave both rows 100% width but they leave out space in the right.
2. I need `<hr>` lines in three Bootstrap columns, they extend beyond the columns and I can't limit them with a percentage of width. 
   I gave `.navbar-brand` and `.navbar-collapse` negative margins left and right. When I resize the window they slip out of sight and back, is there a way for margins to remain stable?
3. There's some white space in the right and below the footer. I found several threads here addressing this issue but none of the solutions I tried worked.

Comment: I don't know how formatting ended up so bad, "Some other issues:" and the following sentences were on different lines.

Comment: Also it was "I need <hr> lines"

Comment: have you tried importing this way `@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster+Two');` ?

Comment: Tried now, there's no difference.

Comment: Keep posts to one question each, please.

Comment: Note you have a comma instead of a semicolon at the end of `set`. Unless you have another value declared under it, that isn't right and could cause an issue.

Comment: Please add your html code for 1-3 issues.

Answer (score 2):

Try to add a

```
<base href="http://example.com/">
```

at your web file (head section), and

```
src: local('LobsterTwo'), url(http://example.com/fonts/LobsterTwo-BoldItalic.ttf) format('truetype');
```

at your css code to force filepaths refresh at your browser.
I don't know the reason but it should sort out your first issue.

Comment: (If you use three backticks before and after some code, instead of just indentation, you can specify which language you're using to get better highlighting by specifying it after the first set of backticks. So, `\`\`\`css` would make SO not highlight your CSS like JS/other languages [where `//` is a comment].)

Comment: Thanks you, I didn't understand what was I supposed to do with that base href part but just adding that in the CSS worked.

Comment: the base is for 'save' semirelative filepaths at css line like: src: local('LobsterTwo'), url(/fonts/LobsterTwo-BoldItalic.ttf) format('truetype');

Comment: btw. <base> is a line for *.html file, not for *.css

Comment: I suspect that browsers do not refresh file paths synchronously, which can cause such problems as yours.

Comment: Forcing the paths at every place of web code can only refresh them at all browsers cache nooks.